# Microsoft Excel Pivot miscalculation in Sum for positive and negative numbers

Tags: excel, sum, pivot

I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong (probably yes) or there is a problem in Microsoft Excel.

Scenario:
I create a table as below

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Value |
+------+-------+
| Alex | 1.55  |
| Alex | -1.56 |
| Alex | 0.01  |
+------+-------+
```

When I try to get sum of Value in a pivot the result is as below:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Row Labels  | Sum of Value |
| Alex        | -8.67362E-18 |
| (blank)     |              |
| Grand Total | -8.67362E-18 |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I expect the [Sum of Value] to display 0  but it displays a non zero value(-8.67362E-18).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps Excel doesn't use "natural" math but just keeps the numbers as traditional floating point numbers in memory and does standard computer math with it. Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Thanks Julian for your comment. Although this should not be the case for Excel since it has been hugely used in accounting tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is normal behavior with floating point calculation, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214118, it is ugly however since it behaves different in pivot tables and normal excel sheets.

Sheet:

[image]

Formula in `B5` is

=SUM(B2:B4)

As you see, result is 0.

Pivot table:

[image]

As you see, normal calculated sum is **not** 0. And no, pivot tables will not respect setting "Precision as Displayed".

What have I done?

Added a calculated field "Feld1", see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-values-in-a-PivotTable-report-697406b6-ee20-4a39-acea-8128b5e904b8#bmcreate_a_formula, with formula:

=ROUND(Value, 8)

and used this for sum.

Comment: Cheers mate, much appreciated.