# difference in rounding numbers in R vs Excel

Tags: r, excel, rounding

Using this dat `data.frame`

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = c("
SiteID  cat1    cat2    cat3
Site1   3   1   1
Site1   3   2   2
Site1   2   3   3
Site1   2   1   1
Site1   2   2   2
Site1   1   1   2
Site1   1   3   1
Site1   1   2   3
Site1   3   NA  2
Site1   1   2   NA"),header =T)
```

I calculated the `mean` (of `cat1` , `cat2` and `cat3`) and `round`ed it to the nearest integer in R as below

**R results**

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 <- dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(c(cat1, cat2, cat3), na.rm = T),
         avg_round = round(avg))
head(dat1, 10)
# A tibble: 10 × 6
#   SiteID  cat1  cat2  cat3      avg avg_round
#   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1   Site1     3     1     1 1.666667         2
#2   Site1     3     2     2 2.333333         2
#3   Site1     2     3     3 2.666667         3
#4   Site1     2     1     1 1.333333         1
#5   Site1     2     2     2 2.000000         2
#6   Site1     1     1     2 1.333333         1
#7   Site1     1     3     1 1.666667         2
#8   Site1     1     2     3 2.000000         2
#9   Site1     3    NA     2 2.500000         2
#10  Site1     1     2    NA 1.500000         2
```

Both `2.5` and `1.5` have been rounded to `2`

This is different from Excel results where `2.5` has been rounded to `3` and `1.5` has been rounded to `2`. I can do the same in R using `ceiling` but ceiling will change `1.3` to `2` which is not what I want.

**Excel results**

[image]

where

```
avg = AVERAGE(B2,C2,D2)
avg_round = ROUND(E2, 0)
```

Any suggestions why `1.5` and `2.5` both have been rounded to `2`? and is there any way to get the same Excel results in R?

Comment: `?round` describes how R rounds to the nearest even.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks. Which function will round to the nearest integer?

Comment: `floor`, `ceiling`, and `trunc` return integers.

Comment: @effel
using `trunc`, I will get 1.5 as 1 which I don't want (I want 1.5 as 2).
using `floor`, I will get 1.5 as 1

Comment: `round` is programmed in a statistically sound manner. Since .5 is exactly halfway between integers, you want it to go each direction half the time so as not to shift the distribution. If you want it to round up, add a tiny amount to whatever you're rounding.

Comment: @alistaire
This means I can't reproduce the rounded values I got in excel using any function in R

Comment: @alistaire I don't think that's correct. What appears to be inconsistency is the result of rounding a `dbl`: "Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard is expected to be used, ‘_go to the even digit_’.  Therefore ‘round(0.5)’ is ‘0’ and ‘round(-1.5)’ is ‘-2’.  However, this is dependent on OS services and on representation error (since e.g. ‘0.15’ is not represented exactly, the rounding rule applies to the represented number and not to the printed number, and so ‘round(0.15, 1)’ could be either ‘0.1’ or ‘0.2’)."

Comment: @aelwan Of course you can. Add a tiny amount, like I said above:  `dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(c(cat1, cat2, cat3), na.rm = T),
         avg_round = round(avg + .0000001))`

Comment: @alistaire
Great. Many thanks for your time and help

Comment: @effel Floating point error actually helps here, weirdly, assuming it's evenly distributed, as it will push the number opposite directions evenly. The function still works the way it says; you just may not have the number you think you have.

Comment: Trying to match calculations from Excel exactly is an exercise in frustration. For one thing, Excel uses a closed-source custom algorithm to fight round-off error, so it doesn't fully comply with ieee standards: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36452194/4996248