# Decimal Point results in excel are not equal to those in home calculator

Tags: excel

Why the decimal point numbers resulted by dividing two numbers in excel are not exactly the same as the answers in home calculator.

for example:
In excel___
C1 : 3853093
C2 : 108,810
=C1/C2  => 35.41135921

In calculator:
3853093 ÷ 108810 = 35.411203

if I take and make further calculations by the result from excel with 6 decimal point, there will be a difference in final result according to the actual value.

Please Help me...Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Excel not round according to 8-byte IEEE 754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452194/why-does-excel-not-round-according-to-8-byte-ieee-754)

Comment: In Excel I get 35.41120301 - did you make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you entered the data correctly in Excel?

I am getting 35.411203 in both Excel and my phone's calculator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks...sir.I have got the point. Actually, I needed to add Round func: to the two inputs...my excel calculated original resulted value 3853093 with some decimal points and I saw the decimal points when I double click the cell.:)